# nodejs forever detect SIGKILL or SIGINT event

Tags: node.js, process, forever, sigint, sigkill

I launch a nodejs program on server running `Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-74-generic x86_64)`, using forever version `v0.15.2`.

In my program (IoT1.js), I need to detect when it is killed (for another launch) so that I can write the last states of the connected clients. The simplified version of my program:

```
const WebsocketServer = require("websocket").server
... // websocket listener

const jsonfile = require("jsonfile")
...

process.on('SIGINT', () => { // also tried SIGKILL, not working either
  console.log("KILL fired")
  jsonfile.writeFileSync("./someLastState.json", states)

  // process.exit(-1)
})
```

Then from `ssh` terminal, I tried these combinations:

```
forever start -p ./ -l lIoT1.log -e eIoT1.log -c node IoT1.js
forever stop <pid>

forever start -p ./ -l lIoT1.log -e eIoT1.log -c node IoT1.js
forever stop <pid> --killSignal=SIGINT // or SIGKILL

forever start -p ./ -l lIoT1.log -e eIoT1.log -c node IoT1.js --killSignal=SIGINT
forever stop <pid>

forever start -p ./ -l lIoT1.log -e eIoT1.log -c node IoT1.js --killSignal=SIGINT
forever stop <pid> --killSignal=SIGINT
```

but none works! i.e. "KILL fired" is not printed (I used `tail -f lIoT1.log` to continuously read its output) and `someLastStates.json` is not created.

What should I do to catch this KILL signal, so that my nodejs has the last chance to write down some file before actually killed?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for catching `SIGTERM` on Linux systems. I've read you cannot catch a `SIGKILL`. For `SIGINT` you can catch that when you terminate with `CTRL+C`, but for termianting via `forever stop(all)` I use to catch the `SIGTERM` signal